# iPhone App Dev - Loading View From View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a questionnaire viewcontroller class. This instantiates several questionviewcontrollers (each questionviewcontroller has an associated view).

How do I get the questionnaire to load these question views associated with their questionviewcontrollers....

EDIT:

```
-(void) setQuestions{
    for (NSDictionary *q in self.questions) {       
        /* Create our Question object and populate it */
        QuestionViewController *question = [[QuestionViewController alloc]init];        
        [question setQuestionId:[q objectForKey:@"questionId"] withTitle:[q objectForKey:@"question"] number:[q objectForKey:@"questionNumber"] section:[q objectForKey:@"sectionId"]];
        /* Add it to our question (mutable) array */
        [questionArray addObject:question];
        [question release];
    }
}
```

The above method is called in the viewDidLoad method of the QuestionnaireViewController and is where the QuestionViewControllers are created. Each one has an associated view with a next button.

Comment: How are you loading the controllers? Post the code, please.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with sending and receiving data from PHP.

Comment: Its hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do here but it sounds a little like you are trying to use UIViewControllers where UIViews would make more sense.  Are you showing one question at a time or a list of several?

Comment: @Dancreek, I'm showing one question at a time...Each question has its own view. I'm storing the questionviewcontrollers in an NSMutableArray. My aim is to iterate and load each one on the press of a button..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what you mean when you say, "How do I get the questionnaire to load these question views".

Are you just asking how to display a QuestionViewController when a question is selected?  If so, this sounds like a navigation based application.  You would typically use a UINavigationController as your top level view controller in your app delegate, setting your QuestionaireViewController as the rootViewController of your UINavigationController.  Then, when the user selects a question in your QuestionaireViewController, you can display its controller using:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:questionViewController animated:YES];
```

If instead you're asking how you can display the views for these QuestionViewControllers as subviews of your QuestionaireViewController, the short answer is don't do it (at least not under iOS 4.x).  Apple's view controller framework is not designed to support using nested view controllers to manage multiple subviews simultaneously.  The documentation states that each view controller should correspond to one full-screen view on iPhone.  iPad changes these rules slightly for things like split views and popovers, but it's still not designed to let you nest view controllers within your own custom view controllers.

(In truth it is technically possible to use multiple view controllers to manage different subviews on a single screen, but doing so properly requires expert knowledge of how the view controller framework is designed so that you can properly delegate all the various UIViewController methods and properties like viewWillAppear:, navigationController, tabBarController, etc.  You're generally better off following Apple's advice and using one view controller per screen.)